# How do I stop Geoip from connecting to the internet every time I boot?

Tags: indicator

I'm trying out ubuntu 12.04 and I noticed that a process called Geoip is connecting to the internet at every boot/login. Why is this necessary? How do I disable this behavior?

Comment: I'm posting this as a comment as I'm not sure it's an answer, but is it possible to identify the process and then rename its file(s) to stop it loading? (I just tried this with geoclue-master but it broke my indicator-datetime. Annoying.)

Answer (score 4):

I stumbled upon a way to disable this connection *(this may only apply to 12.10)*.

- Open your dconf editor: `$ dconf-editor`
- Navigate to the `com/ubuntu/geoip` option
- Set the value of `geoip-url` to nothing "".

Done. Happy days, no more geoip connections.

Disclaimer: I don't know if there any negative effects of disabling geoip provider connections in the way described above, because I still don't fully understand why this connection must call home.

See the SO question [I have permanent connections to Canonical servers, what are they for?](https://askubuntu.com/a/145384/32580) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no way to disable the geoip check.  It is currently used to determine if your timezone has changed.  In the future we should really add an option to disable it or at least reduce the dependency on the geoclue-ubuntu-geoip package to a recommends so users can just un-install that.  I just tested that and it breaks indicator-datetime, I will make sure that gets addressed for 12.10.

Comment: Just for the record, since I'm using autovpn, this feature is completely useless.